# I would like to exclude tags from search results

Tags: feature-request, search

I'm thinking of contributing to Stack Overflow by answering the unanswered questions, but when I filter by my watch tags, I get 1.7 million questions! So it would be helpful if I could exclude tags from search results to whittle down the questions even more to the ones I can answer.

Also it would be helpful if this feature was **visible** in a the graphical user interface, rather than just be a boolean search string feature.

Someone suggested a question asking how to hide questions with certain tags from the feed on the home page. This is **not** my intention as I am browsing the unanswered questions.

Comment: You may want to pay some attention to featured posts... There is non-zero chance that announcement tells you that both lead to the same place...

Comment: You may also be interested in this help topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics

Comment: I'm not trying to hide questions with certain tags from the feed on the home page, as I am browsing the unanswered questions.

Comment: it is visible in the interface, https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @KevinB It's not visible in the interface. Instead it's asking me to type syntax into the search box. Anyway, I tried to do what the instructions said in the page, and it didn't work because I reached the character limit. I'm following 28 tags, so that means the seach query is very long, so to add tags to include with the `-` operator, the search query becomes longer, and I can't make search queries that long.

Comment: @desbest when you click into the searchbox, you can click "Search Help" which lists all the different ways you can modify the search query to find what you need.

Comment: Yes but you didn't read my comment properly. I'm following **28** tags, so that means the seach query is very long, so to add tags to include with the - operator, the search query becomes longer, and I can't make search queries that long.

Comment: Please take note of the `intags:mine` filter.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-[tag]`. Examples:

- Search for [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) questions without [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): [`[gcc] -[c++]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc%20-c%2b%2b)
- Search for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions without [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html): [`[javascript] -[html]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20-html)
- Search for [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) questions without [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript): [`[node.js] -[javascript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js%20-javascript)

---

@SamuelLiew has created a userscript called [Searchbar & Nav Improvements](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#searchbar--nav-improvements) that presents an advanced search GUI when the search bar is focused.

Screenshot from the GIF on the GitHub README:

[image]

[GitHub repository for all userscripts by @SamuelLiew](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

Comment: I think you may have missed the second paragraph of the OP...

Comment: I tried to do the instructions, and it didn't work because I reached the character limit. I'm following 28 tags, so that means the seach query is very long, so to add tags to include with the `-` operator, the search query becomes longer, and I can't make search queries that long.

Comment: @desbest try removing spaces in the minus symbol. Also, are you doing is:q? There's no need for that since only questions have tags.

Comment: What is `is:q`?

Comment: @desbest It's a boolean filter to search for questions only.

Comment: @desbest I've updated this answer to include a method with a GUI